# How to add class to tr

Tags: jquery, addclass

I need add a classs to "tr" prev with jquery in the next html

```
<tr>
    <td>content A</td>
    <td>content B</td>
    <td>conten N....</td>
    <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info">
            <input type="radio" id="offer" class="ofer-sel" name="offerid" required="" value="10">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

how can I do this with jquery when the radio buttons is checked?

regards!

Comment: `addClass` function.

Comment: What do you mean by `to "tr" prev`? To add a class to a `<tr>` is simple, using `prev` doesn't really make sense with the code you've provided.

Comment: You can do it, but is the right way to go? check the atributes here: [HTML <tr> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat confusing question here, but I'll try to work with it.

It seems to me like this would be your desired function, but it's hard to tell when you just want to interact with the previous row (if you click the top row, there is no previous row, and I don't see why it'd be important in either case):

```
$('.ofer-sel').change(function(){
  $('tr').removeClass('checked');
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('checked');
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/ku7x2kmh/

This might include any other information you were looking for with this answer (though I don't necessarily see it's purpose - not to say there isn't one - I just don't see it):

```
$('.ofer-sel').change(function(){
  //add class to previous row
  $(this).closest('tr').prev().addClass('previous');
  //remove class from previous row
  $(this).closest('tr').prev().removeClass('checked');
  //add class to this row
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('checked');
  //remove class from this row
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('previous');
});
```

And an oddly behaving fiddle with that in it for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/p8x87ccq/

Answer (score 1):

In jquery we use `.addClass` method to add class in particular element .
This code might work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table tr').addClass('classname');
});
```

Comment: Hi! thanks but I need add class when the radio button is checked.

Comment: instead of '$(document).ready(' u need to use $( "#checkboxid" ).on( "click",function(){
$('table tr').addClass('classname');
});

Comment: Yes, but this addclass to all TR and I need only for the same tr or the prev

Comment: your question is not clear to me . u need to give more  description about your problem.